Issues with ChromaDB vector store when deploying to Streamlit due to pysql3 version in deployment environment
I'm deploying an app in Streamlit which uses ChromaDB as vector store. The app works perfectly fine locally, but on deployment environment it throws this error:

RuntimeError: [91mYour system has an unsupported version of sqlite3. Chroma requires sqlite3 >= 3.35.0.

I found some old threads where people have asked the same question and applied the solution suggested in those threads:

added pysqlite-binary==0.5.1.3380300 and
pysqlite3==0.5.2 into requirements.txt (version might differ for others)

insert the following on top of the app:
import("pysqlite3")
import sys
sys.modules['sqlite3'] = sys.modules.pop('pysqlite3')
import sqlite3


I deleted the app and redeployed with the updated requirements.txt file and importing the pymysql3 at the start of the streamlit app. This time, the app will not even deployed as there are issues with instalment of packages already.
Error message:

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pysqlite3   Running setup.py clean
for pysqlite3   Building wheel for pypika (pyproject.toml): started
Building wheel for pypika (pyproject.toml): finished with status
'done'   Created wheel for pypika:
filename=PyPika-0.48.9-py2.py3-none-any.whl size=53724
sha256=61a741c62f31f6c5586397250cbd09d4d4899b7b7e25242193ade312cc21a333
Stored in directory:
/tmp/pip-ephem-wheel-cache-xlw45g8_/wheels/a3/01/bd/4c40ceb9d5354160cb186dcc153360f4ab7eb23e2b24daf96d
Successfully built docx2txt pypika Failed to build pysqlite3

The solution seem to have worked for many people but it will not work on mine.
Just wondering if anyone has any solution that works for them?
Many thanks in advance
